# ¿Por qué no corre el código de ggplot2? geom_rect

Tags: r, ggplot

Hola tengo el siguiente código.

En el data frame `puntos` creo los máximos y mínimos de los ejes "x" y "y".

```
puntos<-data.frame(x1=as.Date(c("1980-01-01","2000-01-01")),
                   x2=as.Date(c("1985-01-01","2005-01-01")),
                   y1=c(-Inf,-Inf),
                   y2=c(Inf, Inf))
```

Al realizar, el gráfico de líneas con el siguiente código la gráfica sale sin problemas.

```
economics %>% 
  ggplot()+
  geom_line(aes(x=date, y=unemploy))+
  geom_rect(data = puntos, aes(xmin=x1, xmax=x2, 
                               ymin=y1, ymax=y2),
            fill = "red", color = "black", alpha=0.1)+
  theme_bw()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuándo cambio la estética del geom_line() en la función ggplot()

```
economics %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=date, y=unemploy))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_rect(data = puntos, aes(xmin=x1, xmax=x2, 
                               ymin=y1, ymax=y2),
            fill = "red", color = "black", alpha=0.1)+
  theme_bw()
```

Sale el siguente error:

`Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'unemploy' not found`

No se supone que si cambio en `geom_rect()` los datos, la estética que se define viene del nombre de las variables de estos nuevos datos?

Creo que estoy entendiendo mal ggplot2. ¿Por qué se da el error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece (no estoy 100% seguro) que el problema es que `geom_rect`, aunque no usa explícitamente los argumentos x y y, los considera hasta cierto punto por estar emparentada con `geom_tile`, que es muy similar y sí permite esos argumentos.

En tu primer código no defines mapeo (aes) en la primera llamada a `ggplot`, entonces todo anda bien.

En tu segundo código sí defines un mapeo y entonces se hereda a los siguientes elementos. `geom_line` los toma y funciona bien. Se supondría que `geom_rect` haga lo mismo, pues le estas definiendo sus propios datos y mapeado, usando solo argumentos válidos para esa función: xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax.

Sin embargo cuando tenemos un argumento "heredable" (definido en la primera llamada a `ggplot`) este se propaga a todas las llamadas posteriores. Cuando un `geom_` particular define su mapeo este se combina con los elementos heredados.

Ejemplo burdo:

```
economics %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = unemploy))
```

`x` se hereda, `y` ye se define directo en la llamada.

Entonces en tu caso `x` y `y` se están heredando a la llamada de `geom_rect`, pero como los datos son `puntos` y ahí no están las columnas entonces el error.

Pero `x`y `y` no debería ser argumentos válidos para `geom_rect`. No deberían y si los llamas explícitamente con un valor válido tienes un warning mentiroso: los ignoro, pero fallo porque no los encuentro.

```
economics %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=date, y=unemploy))+
  geom_rect(data = puntos, aes(x = date, y = unemploy,  #Acá los defino explicitamente
                               xmin=x1, xmax=x2, 
                               ymin=y1, ymax=y2)) +
  geom_line() + 
  theme_bw()

Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : objeto 'unemploy' no encontrado
Además: Warning message:
Ignoring unknown aesthetics: x, y
```

Te regresa el mismo error y un warning que advierte que los aesthetics x y y están siendo ignorados.

Pero si los defines como nulos el código anda:

```
economics %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=date, y=unemploy))+
  geom_rect(data = puntos, aes(x = NULL, y = NULL,  #Acá los defino nulos
                               xmin=x1, xmax=x2, 
                               ymin=y1, ymax=y2)) +
  geom_line() + 
  theme_bw()
```

Otra alternativa, que señala Patricio en un comentario, es usar el argumento `inherits.aes = FALSE` en la llamda de `geom_rect()`. De ese modo se ignoran los mapeados definidos previamente y la función no busca a x y y cuando no hace falta y no los va a encontrar.

Conclusión: `geom_rect` de alguna manera está recibiendo y procesando a x y y. Quizás el warning se emita después de que los buscó y no encontró en los datos `puntos`. Se supone que `x`y `y` no tienen nada que hacer, pero hay un bug o alguna característica no documentada que hace que `geom_rect` los busque y al no encontrarlos en el data.frame `puntos` se produce el error.

No es raro que haya geoms que son wrappers de otros, sospecho que acá el primitivo es `geom_tile` (que sí acepta x y y como argumentos) y que `geom_rect` solo ofrece una interfaz para hacer más fácil usarlo definiendo las esquinas en lugar de centro, alto y ancho.

Comment: Es básicamente lo que dices, y se puede chequear en la documentación de `geom_rect()` el parámetro `inherit.aes` esta en `TRUE` por lo que "hereda" las estéticas del nivel superior, que obviamente no existen en los datos  que usa el `geom_rect()` . La solución más simple, y lo agregaría a tu respuesta, es indicarle al `geom_rect()` el parámetro `inherit.aes = FALSE`. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias, ya actualicé la respuesta, es mucho más simple que definir x y y NULL. La duda que me queda es si este comportamiento (buscar un aes que no aplica para ese geom)  es solo en `geom_rect`  o es un comportamiento generalizado en `ggplot`. En mi caso es la primera vez que lo veo.

Comment: Hasta dónde conozco es un comportamiento generalizado de ggplot, los geoms tienen este parámetro y el valor por defecto es TRUE, es un comportamiento muy útil cuando manejas mas de una fuente de datos pero que comparten la misma estructura, pero ciertamente en estos casos es un problema.

Comment: Suena razonable, por algo está `inherit.aes =`. Lo que es raro en ese caso es el warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: Las ignora, pero no tanto... En fin, ggplot es una librería gigante y muy compleja, no es raro que tenga estas cosillas. Si se presenta el problema es fácil de solucionar. Gracias!